# Scala: array.toList vs array.to[List]

Tags: arrays, scala

I am wondering what is the difference between .toList vs .to[List] in arrays.  I made this test in the spark-shell and there is no difference in the result, but I don't know what is better to use. Any comments?

```
scala> val l = Array(1, 2, 3).toList
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val l = Array(1, 2, 3).to[List]
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: If you check the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L1252), you will see they are equivalent. `to[Coll]` get the **factory** of Coll and pass `this` as an argument. - `toList` does the same, but explicitly using the `Factory` of List. - I would just use `toList` it reads better _(for me)_ and will save you one indirection call. But in the end, they are the same.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I suggest write this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Luis' comment, the `to[List]` is (as Luis mentioned) actually using a factory parameter to construct the list. However, the linked source is only valid from Scala 2.13+, after the collections overhaul. The syntax you use wouldn't work in Scala 2.13, instead you would have to write `.to(List)`, explicitly passing the factory argument. In previous Scala versions, the method looked like [this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L587). The CanBuildFrom is essentially a factory passed as an implicit parameter.

The reason this method exists is that it is generic beyond collections in the standard library (and you don't have to define every single possible transformation as a separate method). You can use another collections library (e.g. [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze)), and either construct a factory or use an included one, and use the `to(factory)` method. You can also use it in generic functions where you take the factory as a parameter and just pass it on to the conversion method, for example something like:

```
def mapAndConvert[A, B, C](list: List[A], f: A => B, factory: Factory[B, C]): C[B] =
  list.map(f).to(factory)
```

In this example I don't need to know what collection `C` is, yet I can still return one with ease.